# How to hide products in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Is it possible to hide products in magento 2.I tried disabling a product but it's still displayed in the front as "out of stock".I want to hide products to avoid deleting them for good in case i need them some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock`. **Display Out of Stock Products** Select no to hide the products

Comment: after doing this should i fush magento cache ?

Comment: Yes please flush the cache

Comment: i flushed magento cache 3 times and i also put the product's quantity "out of stock"(product now in the backoffice disabled and out of stock) but still displayed in the frontoffice

Comment: Is your site in development or production mode. Any third party cache configured

Comment: i'm really new to using magento but my site in online if that helps.I think what is missing is that cron command !!

Comment: Setting display out of stock products to no, hides it from category listing and search pages, but the product page will be displayed. This is done so that page is still visible to search engines without 404 errors.